# Запятая перед "да так и"

Tags: пунктуация

В Нацкорпусе чуть ли не подряд идут примеры схожей структуры, но одни с запятой, другие без.

- > Волк зевает во всю свою волчью пасть, да так и засыпает с разинутой
  > пастью...
- > Он как-то руку боком просунул, ободрал её, да так и завяз и повис.
- > Шёл, шёл да так и поплыл.
- > Звонила Тамара, и с первых же её слов Нейман сел да так и просидел до
  > конца разговора.

В чём разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Союз ДА** может иметь **три значения:** соединительное, противительное, присоединительное.

**Союзное соединение ДА И** обычно имеет присоединительное значение, в этом случае запятая ставится: Волк зевает во всю свою волчью пасть, да так и засыпает с разинутой пастью... Он как-то руку боком просунул, ободрал её, да так и завяз и повис.

Но в словаре Кузнецова (для союза ДА) **особо оговаривается такой вариант**: Указывает на неожиданный переход от одного действия к другому, **нарушающему или завершающему ход событий**. Пошёл в лес за грибами да и заблудился. Я слушала да и заснула. Только собрались отца к себе прописать, он возьми да и умри.

В этом случае нет запятой, **значение соединительное**, а ДА выступает в роли частицы: *Шёл, шёл да так и поплыл. Нейман сел да так и просидел до конца разговора.*